# Is there any example to generate a OAS3 html from yaml file using open-api generator

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

Is there any way to auto generate HTML file (same look and feel as swagger-editor) using maven dependency / plugin using existing YAML file?

Note: I'm targeting for **OAS3** version.

Even the swagger editor > Generate Client > html OR html2 generates the look and feel which is different.

Will the following site https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos be helpful in this aspect?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a Swagger UI page, like http://petstore.swagger.io?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the swagger UI page reflect the project's openapi's yaml file.